# Automizing process

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1,892 rows which I have to copy and paste in a certain way onto another sheet. So I started doing copy and paste manually, but I don't have much time, so I tried to do it with a macro. The problem is that I have to change the range, etc all the time, so I would like to know if there is any way to do it like +8 rows and so on. I paste here the code for you to understand what I am trying to do:

```
Sheets("Sales data").Select
Range("F258:N258").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sales per month").Select
Range("G2306").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Sheets("Sales data").Select
Range("A258:E258").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sales per month").Select
Range("A2306:E2314").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C2297").Select

Sheets("Sales data").Select
Range("F259:N259").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sales per month").Select
Range("G2315").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Sheets("Sales data").Select
Range("A259:E259").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sales per month").Select
Range("A2315:E2323").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C2297").Select
```

So the code to execute would be this one, one of the two paragraphs, but now I would like to automatize in order to not repeat each time where I need to change the range. So, the first range would always be plus +1 until row 1,892. The second would be +9, for example: G2315, G2324, G2333, etc. For the third range, it would be +1, as for the first one (it would be the same) and for the last range, it would be the second range for the letter A + 8 for the letter E.

Please please if someone could help, it would mean a lot, I really need to get this right!! Thank youuuu

Comment: Could you reword your question please - _So, the first range would always be plus +1 until row 1,892. The second would be +9, for example: G2315, G2324, G2333, etc. For the third range, it would be +1, as for the first one (it would be the same) and for the last range, it would be the second range for the letter A + 8 for the letter E._  No idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, using a loop which runs until the source row is empty:

```vb
Sub Testnumber15()
    
    Const BLOCK_SIZE As Long = 9 '# of rows in each "block"
    
    Dim wsSD As Worksheet, wsSPM As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim rngDest1 As Range, rngDest2 As Range
    
    Set wsSD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales data")
    Set wsSPM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales per month")
    
    Set rng1 = wsSD.Range("F258:N258")
    Set rng2 = wsSD.Range("A258:E258")
    
    Set rngDest1 = wsSPM.Range("G2306")
    Set rngDest2 = wsSPM.Range("A2306:E2306").Resize(BLOCK_SIZE)
    
    Application.Screenupdating = False
    Do While Application.CountA(rng1) > 0 'loop while rng1 has any data
        
        rng1.Copy
        rngDest1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    
        rng2.Copy rngDest2
        
        Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1) 'next row down
        Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(1)
        
        Set rngDest1 = rngDest1.Offset(BLOCK_SIZE) 'next BLOCK_SIZE rows down
        Set rngDest2 = rngDest2.Offset(BLOCK_SIZE)
        
    Loop
   
End Sub
```